# How to get out of a loop of inter-updating widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am writing a small GUI with PyQt5 that links two series of values (let's call them a, b, c and alpha, beta respectively). All numbers are input via QDoubleSpinBox widgets.

These numbers can be computed from each other via two functions:

```py
alpha, beta = f1(a,b,c)
a,b,c = f2(alpha, beta)
```

The problem is that since the signal of a,b,c triggers a slot modifying alpha,beta and vice-versa, I get stuck in an infinite loop of inter-updating widgets as soon as I change the value of something, until the UI crashes. When commenting out the the update along one or the other direction, things work fine.

Without the details of the GUI layout, this is basically what I am doing:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QDoubleSpinBox)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # initialize UI and widgets (not shown)
        self.initUI()

        # update alpha beta
        self.a.valueChanged.connect(self.update_alphabeta)
        self.b.valueChanged.connect(self.update_alphabeta)
        self.c.valueChanged.connect(self.update_alphabeta)

        # update abc
        self.alpha.valueChanged.connect(self.update_abc)
        self.beta.valueChanged.connect(self.update_abc)


        def update_alphabeta(self):
            alpha,beta = f1(self.a, self.b, self.c)
            self.alpha.setValue(alpha)
            self.beta.setValue(beta)

        def update_abc(self):
            a,b,c = f2(self.alpha, self.beta)
            self.a.setValue(a)
            self.b.setValue(b)
            self.c.setValue(c)
```

I could not find a proper solution so far. Perhaps there is something fundamentally flawed in the way I am trying to do that.

Comment: For the resolution of the problem we need more information: let's say that the user changes "a" or "b" or "c" so obviously programmatically "alpha" and "beta" must change, and consequently it must change "a", "b" "and "c" but this should no longer change" alpha "and" beta "since this last change was not made by the user. Am I right?

Comment: That is right, that's how I would expect it to behave. However, a,b,c and alpha,beta keep being updated continuously until the program crashes. I should mention that for each a,b,c there is a unique combination of alpha,beta and vice-versa. I have the feeling it gets stuck in this loop because of floating number approximation and it just never finds a steady state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want that if "a", "b" or "c" is modified by the user you should only modify "alpha" and "beta" using f1, and change "alpha" and "beta" it does not change "a", "b" and "c". The same for the case of "alpha" and "beta" with f2. If so, then the solution is to block the emission of signals from the elements that are changed programmatically since this is the reason for the infinite recursion using [`blockSignals()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals).

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def f1(a, b, c):
    return 1 / (1 + a ** 2 + b ** 2 + c ** 2) ** 0.5, a + b + c


def f2(alpha, beta):
    return (
        alpha + beta,
        1 / (alpha ** 2 + beta ** 2 + 1),
        (alpha ** 2 + beta ** 2) ** 0.5,
    )


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        max_f = 1.7976931348623157e308
        min_f = -max_f
        self.m_a_dsp = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            value=0,
            valueChanged=self.update_alpha_beta,
            minimum=min_f,
            maximum=max_f,
        )
        self.m_b_dsp = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            value=0,
            valueChanged=self.update_alpha_beta,
            minimum=min_f,
            maximum=max_f,
        )
        self.m_c_dsp = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            value=0,
            valueChanged=self.update_alpha_beta,
            minimum=min_f,
            maximum=max_f,
        )
        self.m_alpha_dsp = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            value=0,
            valueChanged=self.update_a_b_c,
            minimum=min_f,
            maximum=max_f,
        )
        self.m_beta_dsp = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            value=0,
            valueChanged=self.update_a_b_c,
            minimum=min_f,
            maximum=max_f,
        )

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_a_dsp, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_b_dsp, 0, 2, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_c_dsp, 0, 4, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_alpha_dsp, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_beta_dsp, 1, 3, 1, 3)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_alpha_beta(self):
        alpha, beta = f1(
            self.m_a_dsp.value(), self.m_b_dsp.value(), self.m_c_dsp.value()
        )
        for spinbox, value in zip(
            (self.m_alpha_dsp, self.m_beta_dsp), (alpha, beta)
        ):
            spinbox.blockSignals(True)
            spinbox.setValue(value)
            spinbox.blockSignals(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_a_b_c(self):
        a, b, c = f2(self.m_alpha_dsp.value(), self.m_beta_dsp.value())

        for spinbox, value in zip(
            (self.m_a_dsp, self.m_b_dsp, self.m_c_dsp), (a, b, c)
        ):
            spinbox.blockSignals(True)
            spinbox.setValue(value)
            spinbox.blockSignals(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That seems to be what I need! Thanks a lot! I can't try it right now, but that definitely looks like it!

Comment: I confirm this is working perfectly!
Short question regarding the solution you provide: Why is the decorator @QtCore.pyqtSlot() necessary? I tested with and without it, it's the same result.

Comment: @Vesp It is not necessary but it is good, read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator